# Can not ssh to my VM created using openstack from out of openstack server?

Tags: openstack

I have installed opensatck using devstack on one server[nova, horizon, neutron] which has 1 network card and I trying  to associate floating ip to VMs but not able to access it with its public ip from a machine from same network?
Where is the issue I will be needing 2 network card or it's different issue?

Comment: Have you checked your firewall rules for that machine? Assuming you are using default ports, you will need port 22 to be open.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the floating IP from the devstack host? If so, you may need to enable proxy_arp and ip_forward, using (as root or sudoer):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

There are more detailed instructions in a post I wrote here:

http://barakme.tumblr.com/post/70895539608/openstack-in-a-box-setting-up-devstack-havana-on-your